# Get relative path for a file asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an MVC4 application, one controller method takes some files (this files has some Json Objects), read it proccessit then deleteit.

Those files are uploaded to my site using ftp. My Project structures is sometrhing like this

```
wwwroot
  bin
  content
  images
  scripts 
  suscribers // This is my ftp folder 
    _suscriber1
      _proccess1
        file1.txt //This is a Json file 
        file2.txt 
        ...
      _proccess2
      ...
    _suscriber2 
    ...
```

All my files (file1.txt...) are loaded ok. At my controller, i'm trying to read file1.txt this way:

```
string suscriberDir= string.Format("_{0}", suscriber.Id);
string[] laPath = {System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "suscribers", suscriberDir};
string lcPath = Path.Combine(laPath);
string[] laPath2 = { lcPath, "_proccess1" , "_File1.txt" };
lcPath = Path.Combine(laPath2);
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(lcPath);
string personas = reader.ReadToEnd();
reader.Close();
```

My problema is that it is throwing me a filenotfound exception.

What is the right way to read file1.txt and get its content?

Comment: Have you debugged this code? I think that "CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory" is the "bin\Debug" folder.  You should try throwing a breakpoint in there and do old-fashion debugging

Comment: Yes I'm debuging it .. "old fashion"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try using `Server.MapPath("_File1.txt");`

Comment: _File1.txt could exist in several dirs.. this is the way ?

Comment: Yes, you were right, just that my controller is at bin dir. My final solution  `Server.MapPath("../suscribers/_suscriber1/_proccess1/File1.txt")`.